# Latex build fail on invalid reference

Tags: latex, hyperref

I would like Latex build to fail when I have an invalid reference (I'm using nameref). Right now I only get a warning:

```
Found missing reference warnings.
LaTeX Warning: Reference `foo' on page 120 undefined on in
```

How can I configure Latex to give me an error instead?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3244908/407651

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] that allows us to reproduce the warning?

Comment: @mzjn That solution will translate all warnings to errors. I would like a solution that only covers the reference warning.